How to search for a element in list in VS Code Data Wrangler (Interactive Jupyter)
Before a recent update I was able to search for elements in a list (of strings) in python, using the show variable snap shot under the jupyter. I am using the python interactive jupyter.

But with the update I am unable to search it.

Would like to know if there is a way to search for an element in a list using data wrangler?

There is a prompt which says choose column to reveal. I tried to click on top of the list and search, but was unable to get it to search.

I tried creating a pandas data frame and searching for elements, but unable to search for individual elements in a column.

There is also Find and replace and Sort and filter options. But they don't display the data in real time.



